# Disable User Account in Active Directory using C# Code

Tags: c#

I have created c# Winform application. via which I can disable an active directory user account using C# code. I have added a textbox in which I can enter my AD username. But unable to figure how to link this textbox entry with below code?

```
private static void DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
                (principalContext, username);
        userPrincipal.Enabled = false;
        userPrincipal.Save();
        Console.WriteLine("Active Directory User Account Disabled successfully through UserPrincipal");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more clear on your question and be descriptive when adding code.

Comment: yes my mistake. i have added few description.
I want to disable Active directory user using C# but unable to figure how to link textbox entry with this code.

Comment: What are you referring to as "textbox entry"? C# Forms application TextBox?

Comment: yes c# Form Application text box in which i can enter username, and then use this entered username in further code (attached coded in first post].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following example:

**C# CODE**

First add an event click to your button:

```
// Button click event
private void btnDisableAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // When the user clicks the button
    String _ADUserName = textBox1.Text; // <-- The textbox you enter your username?

    // Call the method below 'DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal'
    DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(_ADUserName); // <-- Pass in the user name via the local variable
}
```

Then define your method in the **same class** due to protection level is private
otherwise if it is defined in another class / assembly ref then make the protection **level public**

```
// Private Method
private static void DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
                (principalContext, username);
        userPrincipal.Enabled = false;
        userPrincipal.Save();

        MessageBox.Show("AD Account disabled for {0}", username);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

To enable the account:

```
// Private Method with return type "Boolean" to determine if the method succeed or not.
private static bool EnableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(string username)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity
        (principalContext, username);
        userPrincipal.Enabled = true;
        userPrincipal.Save();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return false;
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String _ADUserName = textBox1.Text; // <-- The textbox you enter your username?

    // Check if the account is enabled
    if (EnableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(_ADUserName))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("AD Account Enabled for {0}", _ADUserName );
        this.StatusTextBox.Text = "Account Enabled";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I did exactly, entered the username in textbox, but getting following error.
`A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Add your button click event and code of your class to your question so that I can analyze it.

Comment: you are passing the variable as a string: DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal("_ADUserName"); Change this to DiableADUserUsingUserPrincipal(_ADUserName); So in other words remove the qoutes

Comment: Worked really well.
thank you for help, time and above all patience to bear my very beginner level annoying queries :)

Comment: No worries, anytime. :)

Comment: I have added an Status Text Box, I want to update result in this text box. I am trying to add like `this.StatuxTextBox.Text` function after ` MessageBox.Show("AD Account Enabled for {0}", username);` , but its not working . Also in message box, its not showing the USERNAME.

Comment: Update the code on pastebin.com and send me the url so that I can see and analyze.

Comment: Updated:
https://pastebin.com/G4vqEZg7
Error is:
`Error 1 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer c:\temp\cprojects\WindowsFormsApplication2\WindowsFormsApplication2\Form1.cs 40 17 WindowsFormsApplication2`

Comment: That is an easy one, you can't use "this" keyword in a static method. First you need to create an instance of the class it self. Do the following: Form1 f1 = new Form1(); Then replace it with f1.StatuxTextBox.Text = username;

Comment: ok i tried this. but StatuxTextBox not updating, only msg box appearing.

https://pastebin.com/9ukBWVrX

Comment: According to the link you sent it is commented out ? //this.StatusTextBox.Text = "Accoutn Enabled"; Remove the "//" forward slashes

Comment: when i remove them, i receive 'this' error as showed above.

Comment: replace this line --> //this.Status.TextBox.Text; WITH this two lines --> Form1 f1 = new Form1(); f1.StatuxTextBox.Text = "Account Enabled"; Then run it again.

Comment: Ok I updated to this,
https://pastebin.com/9ukBWVrX     but still no text appears in `StatusTextBox` window.      I verified that `StatuxTextBox` window is working by fine by adding some text in buttonc clicked events. but its not working on enabled function as showed in pastebin.

Comment: I was finally able to made this. 
[Simple_AD_management_box](https://aacable.wordpress.com/2017/03/30/c-active-directory-management-using-custom-built-app/)